# How to insert into Wordpress Database on click of link?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've got two variables that are set once the wordpress page loads. How can I initiate the insertion of the record once the link is clicked? Everything I've read so far requires a form. This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php 
global $post; 
$wp_user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
$activity_post_id = $post->ID;
?>

<a href="insert_into_database_somehow">Click to Insert into Database</a>

INSERT INTO wp_activities (wp_user_id, activity_post_id, date_added) VALUES ($wp_user_id, $activity_post_id, CURDATE() )
```

Comment: You can append query_string in your url like `?add=true` and based on the condition if `$_GET['add']` is true insert your query. You can also append nonce along with it.

Comment: I've posted some code to point you in the right direction. Forget that last part of your question by the way. You should be interacting with the db using the wpdb class. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a get variable to the end of your link.

E.g.

```
<a href="mylink.com/?track_click">Click to Insert into Database</a>
```

Then in functions.php add some code on init to check for this and run code.

```
function wpse_track_click() {
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['track_click'] ) )
        return false; 

    // add your code to run here.
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_track_click' );
```